# preg_replace causing character encoding error

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, preg-replace, html-entities

I'm using a function to avoid sql injection in my forms. It has worked fine, so far, 'till i've noticed that, when submitting a field, some characters are replaced by html entities and displayed in this way

Form: 
http://prntscr.com/e1eb17

Database:
http://prntscr.com/e1ebah

Through commenting the code, I was able to determine that the following line is causing the error:

```
$sql=preg_replace("/(from|select|insert|drop|table|delete|show tables|where|alter table|add|update|#|\*|--|=|xp_|NULL|KEY|\\\\)/","",$sql);
```

When this line is removed, it works fine.

See the anti-injection function in full:

```
function kill_injection($sql)
{
    if(is_array($sql))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($sql); $i++)
        {   
            $sql[$i]=preg_replace("/(from|select|insert|drop|table|delete|show tables|where|alter table|add|update|#|\*|--|=|xp_|NULL|KEY|\\\\)/","",$sql[$i]);

            if(is_string($sql[$i]))
            {
                $sql[$i]=str_replace("\r\n", " ", $sql[$i]);
                $sql[$i]=str_replace("\n", " ", $sql[$i]);
                $sql[$i]=str_replace("\r", " ", $sql[$i]);              
                $sql[$i]=trim($sql[$i]);    
                $sql[$i]=strip_tags($sql[$i]);  
                $sql[$i]=mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database"), $sql[$i]);
                $sql[$i]=addslashes($sql[$i]);
                $sql[$i]=preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $sql[$i]);
            }           
        }
    }
    else
    {       
        $sql=preg_replace("/(from|select|insert|drop|table|delete|show tables|where|alter table|add|update|#|\*|--|=|xp_|NULL|KEY|\\\\)/","",$sql);

        if(is_string($sql))
        {
            $sql=str_replace("\r\n", " ", $sql);
            $sql=str_replace("\n", " ", $sql);
            $sql=str_replace("\r", " ", $sql);  
            $sql=trim($sql);    
            $sql=strip_tags($sql);
            $sql=mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database"), $sql);  
            $sql=addslashes($sql);
            $sql=preg_replace('/(\s)+/', ' ', $sql);
        }
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

I'm not a regex expert - in fact, I took that regex from a website, so I have no idea what's going on. Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you need to do all of this when you could just use parameters and be done with injections?

Comment: Parameters? Please, be more specific. I'm still a beginner in information security

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php for example. There is always a ready-made way to handle things so you don't have to make a possibly broken implementation yourself

Comment: Or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php when using mysqli specifically

Comment: I use procedural PHP, not sure if that would work with it, @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: What else kind of PHP is there? If you use SQL you can use parameters in queries and that's it.

Comment: The oop class oriented kind, that's veeeery different :O. But I'll try it anyway. Thanks for the tip!